# Can a previous employer contribute to my closed 401k after termination

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement-plan

I was terminated in late January of 2020 by my previous employer. I had worked for them for 5 years and 2 months. I had over 5k in my 401k account and withdrew it all a couple days after termination (1/30/2020). Today (March 10, 2020) I logged onto my 401k account and noticed I now have a little over $800 back in my 401k account. Next to the contribution it says "employer additional" posted on 2/25/2020, a month after my termination. Is the $800 mine??

Comment: Perhaps the 800 is earnings?

Comment: Thank you for your response but What do you mean? Like is it mine or the company's money now?

Comment: I'm not posting an answer; but a 401(k) invests in stocks, and stocks pay earnings, so perhaps you were due earnings that only got paid after you closed the account.  Another possibility is that your last paycheck put some money into the account after you closed it.  I'm not knowledgeable enough though so I'm just commenting on some possibilities, but I am not sure enough to answer.

Comment: Definitely don't think I made enough to get a deposit of $800 but the first part makes a lot of sense. Thanks so much for your input Andy!!

Comment: Don't walk away from your question just yet, make sure you read any actual answer that gets posted.  I'm just wildly guessing and could be very wrong.

Comment: @Andy if the funds were withdrawn then there would be nothing to get earnings on. Most likely it is some sort of safe harbor or other benefit that had accrued prior to termination.

Comment: Does your company match contributions? Do they pay any profit-sharing? Or do they normally deposit money from other employees who have quit but forfeited their 401k money due to not being vested? Could be any of these.

Comment: Did you have deductions from severance or vacation paid out on regular payperiod checks after the formal separation on 1/30?

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons that money can be added after your last day of work.

- It can be money from your last paycheck.
- It can be money from the payout of vacation/sick/PTO.
- It can be money from a severance payout.
- It can be matching funds from any of these contributions.
- It can be a profit sharing payment. My employer pays the bonus to all employees who worked 1000 hours the previous year. The payment to my 401(k) is in March each year.
- It can be some other bonus.

To determine the source and if it your funds, or if it is from the company and you might be partially or 100% vested, you will need to look at the activity section of the account. Every 401K I have had tells me the source of all deposits, and the vesting status of those funds. The account balance section should also tell you if is partially or 100% vested.

I would expect that at 5 years and two months you are 100% vested, but if you had worked fewer years these funds might be only partially vested if they were from the company.

You mention that the website identifies the transaction as "employer additional". I would look back over the last few years to see if there are other deposits with the same description.

Check your termination paperwork. They should have information on the timing of them paying out your last check, PTO balance, and any severance. In some cases they give you options regarding 401(k) contributions.

Comment: It could also be a true up payment.